# Rails 3.0.9: config.active_record not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have upgraded from Rails 3.0.7 to Rails 3.0.9 and I am now getting the following error in my config/application.rb:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:78:in `method_missing': undefined method `active_record' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x10107a830> (NoMethodError)
from /Users/mathias/ruby/myapp/config/application.rb:47
```

On line 47 of application.rb I have

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

It seems that

```
config.active_record
```

is not found in Rails 3.0.9 where this worked in 3.0.7. This is regardless of which method I call on config.active_record. When I comment out any usage of config.active_record, the same occurs with config.active_mailer.

And I do a `require "rails/all"` in the application.rb

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You try to use rails `3.0.9` but use `railties-3.1.0`? Seems to be the culprit to me.

Comment: I removed railties 3.1.0 and am now remaining with railties 3.0.9 - the problem remains the same.

Comment: I have also created a clean install of Rails 3.1.0 and dependencies using RVM. I get the same issue. It seems Rails::Application::Configuration does not get initialised with methods "active_record" and "actionmailer" and probably others.

Comment: Anything I try to reference within config/application.rb through the config does not seem to be available: e.g. config.frameworks

Answer (score 0):

Got this to work with 3.1.0 through the steps outlined [here](http://akitaonrails.com/2011/05/31/migrating-my-blog-over-to-rails-3-1-beta). The key bit that made most of my problems disappear was to change `boot.rb` to

```
require 'rubygems'
# Set up gems listed in the Gemfile.
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE']   = File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)
require 'bundler/setup' if File.exists?(ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE']
```